# Constructing Real Numbers using Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?

Tags: reference-request, real-numbers, book-recommendation

$\mathbb{R}$ is generally constructed as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. As Cauchy Completeness and Archimedean Property together are equivalent to the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, there should be a method to construct $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ using the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.

So, is there such a method? If so, could someone point me towards some resources related to this?

Comment: Also posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [Constructing Real Numbers using Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/359711)

Comment: But Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is not available in $\mathbb {Q} $ so how can be use it to build $\mathbb{R} $? Do you mean something else here?

Comment: Nor do all Cauchy sequences converge in $\mathbb{Q}$, but we use it to construct $\mathbb{R}$. I'm asking for the same, with Cauchy Convergence replaced by Bolzano-Weierstrass.